# For funded US PhD programs, why is the summer funding listed separately from the overall stipend?

Tags: phd, funding

I am applying to U.S. PhD programs in mathematics. I have noticed that the school websites (and the official offers I have received) all separate the summer funding from the overall stipend; the summer funding being an additional $3-5k over the $20-40k funding given already for the academic year itself. Why is this the case? Isn't the expectation that students will work full time? If students get all the money, wouldn't it be more convenient (and look more impressive) to just state the full amount as the "stipend"?

Comment: Note that the values you cite are much less than three months at the academic year rate ...

Comment: You're right; the summer funding is more in the neighborhood of $5-8k instead of $3-5k, and perhaps the lower end for the yearly stipend was too low. A specific offer I received is around $35k for the stipend and $7.5k for the summer

Comment: Still though, all those values are less than 1/3rd the academic year rate. I wasn't trying to call out your numbers, but more point out the department is screwing people.

Comment: Is your funding offer as a TA or RA?  There is generally less work for TA's over the summer- the department may spread the available funds around, or some students may end up with no summer TA funding.

Comment: Yes, I'd be expected to work as a TA to receive full funding; I expect you are correct and this is where the disparity comes in, as naturally one cannot TA in the summer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some students get no summer funding.

Answer (score 1):

Some students may be working at internships in the summer.